# React Native: Error "createItemModels creation requirements should not create capability item model for a capability item model that already exists."

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an iOS app using React Native and Firebase.

When I did the following, an error occurred.

1. Install “@react-native-firebase/firestore”
2. cd ios && pod install
3. I got the error "The Swift pod `FirebaseFirestore` depends upon `FirebaseCoreExtension` and `FirebaseFirestoreInternal`, which do not define modules.", so add it to the Podfile.
4. pod install
5. cd .. && react-native run-ios

### Error

> createItemModels creation requirements should not create capability item model for a capability item model that already exists.

How can I solve it?
Is it because you haven't registered with the Apple Developer Program yet?

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.8.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "^0.73.18",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.73.1",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.73.2",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "^0.73.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.18",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}
```

### /ios/Podfile

````
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'app' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'appTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
  end
  
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseAuth', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
end
````

Comment: Please remove you podFile.lock and pods folder and reinstall pod.

Comment: @TalhaAkbar 
thank you! But the error still occurs.

Comment: It's a Xcode bug that was fixed in Xcode 15.1 (confirmed by Apple). React Native and other tools failing to build because of this _warning_ is actually a bug in those tools. Regular xcodebuild always worked, just with a lot of log noise.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add "use_frameworks! :linkage => :static" before "use_react_native" in Podfile.

Comment: Statically linking everything to workaround log output in Xcode is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

Pointing out an emulator successfully started, I don't know why

```
npx react-native run-ios --simulator iPhone 15
```